# Pumping Lemma problems for determining Regular Language and CFL

Tags: pumping-lemma

{a^p b^p; p is a prime number}

{a^p b^p; p is a prime number, m is a fixed number and m≥p≥0}

How do I prove if this is a regular language/context free language (or not)?

Answer (score 0):

1) L = {a^n b^n; n is a prime number} :

So the prove can be done by contradiction. Suppose L is regular, and p is the pumping length.

The test string is w = a^p b^p, w belongs to L, and |w| = 2p >= p

We subdivide w=xyz. There are 3 conditions to prove the pumping lemma:

- from the third condition, |xy| < p, so xy contains only a's
- from the second condition, |y| > 0, so y has the form y = a^k, where 1 <= k <= p
- from the first condition, xy^iz belongs to L for i = 0, 1, 2, ... So if you pump down (i = 0) you got:

w = a^(p - k) b^p , and w does not belongs to L (Because the quantity of a's and b's are different)

So you prove that L is not regular.